# How to delete Sharepoint Online "site"

Tags: sharepoint-online, site

Wow. This should not be this difficult.

**How do I delete these old "sites"?**

[image]

**These have the word "site" in the url:**

[image]

Unfortunately, the docs [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delete-a-sharepoint-site-or-subsite-bc37b743-0cef-475e-9a8c-8fc4d40179fb) say to delete a Sharepoint site, I need to click `Site information` which  I don't see when I click the gear icon.

The instructions say:

```
Note: If you do not see Site information in the Settings panel, work with your SharePoint administrator to get access.
```

I am the admin and only user in the tenant.

See... no `Site Information` option:

[image]

**When I click "Site Permissions" then Site Owners and Members, there is an error shown:**

[image]

**EDIT 1**: Was able to go to the admin center that @Jerry recommended and delete the sites from there.

- Though after deleted in admin center, they did not immediately disappear from Sharepoint.
- Maybe have to wait awhile.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you cannot see the site information link? If so, that means you have no permission to carry out the deletion. What do you mean by

> I am the admin and only user in the tenant.

Are you an admin or a common user?

If you can access the SharePoint admin center, I will suggest you go there and delete a site. You can view all sites and delete them
The link is :https://admin.microsoft.com/sharepoint?page=home&modern=true

[image]

And if you are just a end user without admin permission in that site, simply you cannot delete the site.

Comment: Thats correct, I cannot see the Site Information link when clicking the Gear icon. I am the admin and only user in the entire tenant.

Comment: @SeaDude Do you mean you are the site admin? Or you only mean that you handle the admin work with a common user account? If so, that cannot be done as the account you are using does not have enough permission.

Comment: I have an Office Pro account that includes Sharepoint. I am the only person in the entire tenant. I have to be the admin, because there is not another human being in my tenant. Its just me! At some point I created these "sites". Now I want to delete them but cannot see "Site Information". More details added to OP.

Comment: @SeaDude. Then go to the link I provide, there is a actual SharePoint admin center, you can view and delete the sites.